# Model selection using crossvalidation

Tags: machine-learning

When deciding on a model type, after performing a train-test split on my data and running a k-fold cross validation on the training set for each model (Logistic Reg, SVM, Naive Bayes, etc) I then choose the model that gives the best score for a particular metric (let's say accuracy for simplicity).

If I then score this model on my test set and find a low test score as well as high variance, is it too late to then switch models?

Wouldn't that mean I was using Test data to choose the model?

Thanks and I hope this question isn't too basic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can switch your model after testing it on test data since model is used for testing on test data it was not learning from that data rather it was using it's learning to predict the result based on predictors.
And if you switch the model you will have to train it again and that model will have no relation with earlier model you can again test the new model on test data.
Basically we use test daya because we want to check how well our model is able to generalize. Based on test data we get to know how well our model is and if we need to improve it further. Somehow it would mean that you are choosing your model on the basis of accuracy you get on test data because that is the only way to test the model capability before deploying it on real world just to be sure that our model would be able to generalize well.
Sometimes after deployment we found that model is having hard time to generalize on new data so we again improve it and this cycle continues because nothing is perfect right.